# Traceless in place selection sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer, selection-sort

You are given an arrayA[1..n] of length n with each cell containing a〈height,weight〉pair.  All height values are distinct, and so are all weight values.  The array is sorted in increasing order of the height values.Your task is to design a recursive divide-and-conquer algorithm that given an integer k∈[1,n],finds the entry with the kth smallest weight value.  You are allowed to use only O(1) extra space in every level of recursion.  Though your algorithm is permitted to reorder the entries of A if required,it must restore the original order of the entries before termination.  Your algorithm must run in Θ(n) time.

The algorithm I can think of is selection sort, but i am not able to do it in the time and space complexity asked. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the algorithm may be O(n) in average you may use quicksort. Quicksort can find k-th element in O(n) in average if used till the pivot is proved to be the k-th element itself (O(n^2) worst case and O(n) in average).

Now the tricky part: you need to restore the original array. It is simple for the first iteration of the partition procedure on the sorted array: just run the procedure in opposite direction and reconstruct the initial array. Now the recursive idea emerges: if the pivot happens to be larger than k-th element, you still have left subarray sorted: you may repeat the procedure, find the k-th and restore the array. But if you find that the pivot is lower than k-th element... then restore the array and run the quicksort "reflected" (where you start moving from right to the left). In this case the right subarray from the pivot would be sorted. Repeat procedure recursively.